# How to compand an OFDM signal?

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, ofdm

Im trying to run a simulation of an OFDM system with convolutional coding and u-law compander on MATLAB. The problem is I dont know how to compand the OFDM signal. Do I need to do something to the signal before compressing it? Because value coming out of the ifft block is a complex number.

```
Xofdm_compand= Xofdm_cp; %OFDM with cp
xofdmcompand=abs(Xofdm_compand);
for j=1:Nframe %Number of symbols
    in=xofdmcompand(j,:);
    v=max(abs(in));
    X_compressed(j,:)=compand(in,mu,v,'mu/compressor');
end
```

Edit: Here is the snippet of the code where I compand the signal. Am I doing it wrongly?

Comment: you're confusing things. So, it's not clear what you want to compand where. I don't think I'd be able to give you a great answer unless you're describing for which purpose, on which medium, you're using OFDM, and why you'd apply an speech compander on a digital multicarrier signal. From that arises the understanding of how you can do that.

Comment: You can give great answers anything!

Comment: The purpose in this case is to reduce the PAPR. I have seen on multiple articles that people implement the u-law compander to reduce the PAPR.

Comment: I have not used u-law companding, but have worked on several OFDM PAPR reduction techniques. Each time, what was done was to calculate the amplitudes of the complex values $\rho = \sqrt{I^2 + Q^2}$ and to calculate a correction based on these amplitudes

Comment: Weww, I've tried this. Seems like it giving me correct result. The value of the companded signal all less than 0. Is this normal?

Comment: no. That sounds like a serious bug.

Comment: Hmm seems weird. All I do was feeding the compand function in MATLAB with magnitude of output coming out of the ifft block.

Answer (score 1):

µ-law is defined for real-valued PCM signals only. You will either need to produce a real-valued signal containing OFDM as passband signal, either

- by mixing it to a carrier frequency, or
- by modifying your OFDM system to only produce symmetrical spectrum
  baseband, or
- by u-law coding I and Q separately (but that makes little sense, since a high PAPR happens when **both** I and Q have a high value at the same time, i.e. coding them separately isn't logical),

but all three options wouldn't be "companding OFDM" anymore, that would be "companding a system which, among other things, involves OFDM".

---

General remark: Don't forget that you've got channel coding. It's often better to intentionally completely "delete" isolated subcarriers from extreme-peak OFDM symbols than to  "make whole symbols slightly worse", as the former leads to a certain, but isolated, error, whereas the other has a  *chance* of leading to multiple errors in the same symbol – which would, assuming there's no large interleaver at work, look like a burst error.

---

I think you'd want to read

X. Wang, T. Tjhung and C. Ng, "*Reduction of peak-to-average power ratio of OFDM system using a companding technique*", IEEEE Transactions of Broadcasting, vol. 45m, no. 3, Sept. 1999.

on what they did and what their results are.

While you do that, look at Figure 5:

> [image: SER for the companded signal, not taking power increase into account]

Notice how the second (⛛) curve is the uncompanded one. This looks like for anything but very high SNR, the companded curves are better.

Now, read

A. Mattsson, G. Mendenhall and T. Dittmer, "*Comments on reduction of peak-to-average power ratio of OFDM system using a companding technique*", IEEE Transaction on Broadcasting, vol. 45, no. 4, December 1999.

and especially this paragraph:

> Which shows that there is a significant increase in power
>   for the companded signal. I.e. the SER for the companded
>   signal should in our opinion be compared to the SER for
>   the non-companded signal amplified by 10.9 dB [for the µ=16 case], 17 dB [for the µ=255 case] etc. It appears that the SNR refered to in Fig. 5 on page 307,
>   refers to the signal power of the signal before companding
>   and not the actual SNR of the transmitted signal.

In other words: shift the red (uncompanded) curve 11 dB to the left to compare against the µ=16 case, and by 17 dB to the left to compare against the (standard) µ=255 case.

[image: annotated]

Look how the uncompanded signal (red line) is always better at the same power than the µ=16 companded signal, and how it's better for SNRs > 12 dB for the µ=255 case. I highlighted the amount that uncompanded is better than companded in green for µ=16, and in orange for µ=255.

If your SNR is below 12 dB, you get a SER > 10⁻³, which is a typical design goal for wireless communication; you might want to use a lower modulation than 16-QAM then, which will then typically be an 8-PSK or QPSK. Which is indifferent about  amplitude variation – so instead of companding nonlinearly, you'd just look at the peak in your OFDM symbol and simply either drastically scale a few isolated subcarriers, or the whole symbol slightly. (which you do would depend on how steep the BER curve of your channel decoder is at that point.)

---

---

---

---

**TL;DR**: Literature research shows companding only works for low SNR. There, you might not be in a sweet spot for system design, so my expectations for companding to work are low. 
 Instead, I propose you generally rather design your FEC so that it can live with intentionally broken isolated symbols that you insert on purpose to reduce PAPR.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I forgot to mention that the main purpose of doing the companding is reduce spectral splatter.

Comment: No need to thank me – if you really want to thank me, that's what the upvote button  next to the answer is for.